# Magento 2 Advanced Reporting

Tags: magento2, admin, reports

I have enabled Advanced reporting in my Admin according to http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/reports/advanced-reporting.html but where do I check the subscription status if it is still "pending"?

Comment: you can check in System->integration by the way did you manage to get it working how did you go about it please share I am getting 404 thanks.

Comment: you can try re-authenticating your Advanced Reporting subscription by disabling and re-enabling the service in your Magento admin panel

Comment: And ensure that a Magento Analytics user exists

Comment: @bondimedical can you share your project URL?

Comment: I have managed to fix the issue, was missing an SSL certificate.

Comment: @bondimedical Have you enable the Advance Reporting? if yes how can you explain here please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check it by trying to access the Magento BI account.

https://dashboard.rjmetrics.com/

[image: Magento BI login]

Or if you don't have access to it, you can contact your Magento account manager, the person in charger or your account will know your licenses.